# highcharts legend not set perfectly when using two pie charts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using pie charts with two series. My problem is that legend is not perfectly aligned (`month` name is not perfectly algin).

[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                inside: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.y);
                },
                color:'white',
                distance: -30
            },
              showInLegend:true
        }
    },
   legend: {
        x: -15,
        y: 10,
        symbolHeight: .001,
        symbolWidth: .001,
        symbolRadius: .001,
        itemStyle: {
            fontSize:'12px',
            font: '10pt',
            color: '#666666',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
         },
    },
    series: [{
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: Aug,
            y: 74
        }],
        center: [40, 5],
        size: 50,
    }, {
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
           name: Sep,
            y: 94
        }],
        center: [100, 5],
        size: 50
    }]
});
```

Is there no option for each series having different legends in highcharts? I am trying to adjust x and y coordinates but moving both legends so first legend aligned perfectly but second legend not align perfectly.

Or there is any different option two draw above chart?

Comment: We are gonna need more info then that to be able to help you. What have you tried? Can we set up some code? Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I update my question plz check

Comment: Try to use [itemDistance](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemDistance) property. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4un4wvoe/.

Comment: thanks Paul its working!